# Trouble with kali linux 2017.3 installation

Tags: linux, installation, kali-linux

Trying to install kali linux 2017.3, but when i click on start installer or install using text. The screen goes black and there are bunch of lines instead of menu. What should i do to fix this?

Comment: "bunch of lines instead of menu" -- What lines?

Comment: Like the graphics of the menu is messed up and cannot make out anything.

Comment: Some hardware specifics would be helpful, in addition to describing / summarizing your troubleshooting and research steps thus far, such as where did Google point you towards.

Answer (score 0):

Knowledge of your particular hardware specs would be helpful in providing assistance.

Disabling UEFI makes a difference.

You can always just run it LIVE from a USB if the installation fails.

Verifying your source installer is valid, did you doublecheck the MD5 hashes of your install media with the included hashes.txt at the root of the USB/CD ? That is a frequent reason for failed install/failed LIVE boot.

Trying the latest weekly build is a good idea since it includes the contributions of the community for hardware compatibility.

As of today, you can download [Weekly Build 52](https://cdimage.kali.org/kali-images/kali-weekly/kali-linux-2017-W52-i386.iso) (last one of the year 2017!)
[https://cdimage.kali.org/kali-images/kali-weekly/](https://cdimage.kali.org/kali-images/kali-weekly/kali-linux-2017-W52-i386.iso)